# How to use jar files built by netbeans 8.0 on other windows?

Tags: java, jar

I built `.jar` files of my application. Now I want to share them with my friends.

Do I just copy that `.jar` file over to my friend's system? If not, what else has to be done?

Comment: This isn't really a question for Stack Overflow, but yes, just send them the JAR file.

Comment: but when I send them jar file, it makes unzip file..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your comments you stated that the `.jar` files are unzipping and not running on your friends' computers.

This is usually caused by Java not being installed on their computers. They should get the [Java SE Runtime Environment from Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html) and install it. Afterwards, the jar files can be run with a double-click.

If your friends already have Java installed, they might have to fix their file associations (so `.jar` files no longer open with their ZIP tool).

Answer (score 1):

yes your can share the .jar file by just copy to the new system
if he/she is installed the particular version or latest version of java he/she can run that application

you can also wrap the .jar files into .exe file using some third party applicaion

Comment: if you want .jar file not to unzip then you should wrap that .jar file using some application, i recommend launcher4j http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/

Comment: You guys all... Launch4j is not the solution for OP's problem - their friends probably do not have Java installed and it defaults to their installed zip program.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you created an executable jar it is possible to execute it if the operating system of your friends supports java.

If they need only to use your jar as a library they can import it in their project.

Comment: Yes other system support java, when I send them jar file created by netbean 8, it makes unzip file, not a jar file..

Answer (score 0):

Yes just copy it to your friends machine. That is what jar files are made for.
The reason behind , your jar file is being opened as a zip file , may be your friend have set some unzip tool as a default application to open jar files. Try to open it with JAVA .